# Swagger Springfox annotations not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-2.0

These are the method headers for the sample application I'm trying to make. Unfortunately I don't see the @ApiOperation or @ApiResponse or @ApiResponses annotations taking effect.
I also have a sample class and an Application class(which contains swagger configuration info and the like)

```
@Api(value = "/v1/", description = "Test API", produces = "application/json")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/")
class SampleRestController {

     @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully added"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 416, message = "List is empty") })
   @RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, value = "samples/{sb}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public Map<String, String> sbs(@PathVariable("sb") String sb) {

    }  

   @ApiOperation(
      value = "Seeing where this shows up",
      notes = "we should see this in the implememtation notes",
      response = Sample.class,
      httpMethod = "GET"
    )
        @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully added"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 416, message = "List is empty") })

   @RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, value = "samples/{pb}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public Sample ps(@PathVariable String pb) {

   }

   @RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, value = "samples",
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public Collection<Map<String, String>> cs(@RequestParam(value = "cid", required = true, defaultValue = "")
    String cid) {

   }


}
```

Here is the relevant portion of my swagger json

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"description":"All about the Samples","title":"Samples API","contact":{},"license":{}},"host":"localhost:8080","basePath":"/","tags":[{"name":"sample-rest-controller","description":"Sample Rest Controller"}],



"paths":{


"/v1/samples":{"get":{"tags":["sample-rest-controller"],"summary":"cs","operationId":"csUsingGET","consumes":["application/json"],"produces":["application/json"],"parameters":[{"name":"cid","in":"query","description":"cid","required":true,"type":"string"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Collection«Map«string,string»»"}},"401":{"description":"Unauthorized"},"403":{"description":"Forbidden"},"404":{"description":"Not Found"}}}},


"/v1/samples/{pb}":{"get":{"tags":["sample-rest-controller"],"summary":"ps","operationId":"psUsingGET","consumes":["application/json"],"produces":["application/json"],"parameters":[{"name":"pb","in":"path","description":"pb","required":true,"type":"string"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Sample"}},"401":{"description":"Unauthorized"},"403":{"description":"Forbidden"},"404":{"description":"Not Found"}}}},


"/v1/samples/{sb}":{"get":{"tags":["sample-rest-controller"],"summary":"sbs","operationId":"sbsUsingGET","consumes":["application/json"],"produces":["application/json"],"parameters":[{"name":"sb","in":"path","description":"sb","required":true,"type":"string"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"object","additionalProperties":{"type":"string"}}},"401":{"description":"Unauthorized"},"403":{"description":"Forbidden"},"404":{"description":"Not Found"}}}}},
```

I'm using springfox-swagger2 version 2.1.1 and I'm viewing my UI through the default UI provided by swagger at their live demo app.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was playing around and changed my import from

import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.;

to

import io.swagger.annotations.;

and all the annotations appear to work.
So, looks like the com.wordnik.swagger.annotations import no longer works, or at least doesn't work properly?

Confirmed by Dilip Krish [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/877)